# Why Alert.show() don't display text

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, mxml

```
Alert.show('Text Copied!', 'Alert Box', mx.controls.Alert.OK);
```

the "Text copied!" - is not displaying

mx.controles.Alert.OK - also don't displays in the button itself

only the "Alert Box" displays in the title, why is this happening?

Comment: Can you share a screenshot?  Is it possible that you have a style set in CSS that is inadvertently affecting the Alert box?

Comment: can't post image because i don't have 10 reputation :(( give me an upvote and I will post an image :), in the css all my VBox, HBox, Box are locked by styleName, no its not styles...what else can be?

Comment: @NoobKraker upvoted, you should be able to post your screen shot now.

Comment: @NoobKraker please see the example in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that the constant is bad. Alert maybe uses spark alert, while you pass in the param mx.controls.Alert.OK, meaning it is mx, not spark. try

```
mx.controls.Alert.show('Text Copied!', 'Alert Box', mx.controls.Alert.OK);
```

or use spark alert parameters

Answer (score 0):

try the following code ([css source](http://www.tecrocks.com/2009/03/stlying-flex-alert-using-simple-css.html)), is very simple and works perfectly:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute" creationComplete="init()">
    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.controls.Alert;

            public function init():void{
                Alert.show('Text Copied!', 'Alert Box', mx.controls.Alert.OK);
            }
        ]]>
    </mx:Script>

    <mx:Style>
        Alert{
            color : #124332;
            background-color: #ffffff;
            header-colors : #243322, #243322;
            header-height:19;
            drop-shadow-enabled: true;
            drop-shadow-color :#243322;
            corner-radius :6;
            border-style :solid;
            border-thickness: 1;
            border-color : #243322;
            footer-colors : #243322, #ffffff;
            title-style-name : "title";
        }
        .title{
            font-family :Verdana;
            font-size :10;
            font-weight :bold;
            color :#ffffff;
        }
    </mx:Style>
</mx:Application>
```